# ¿Imprimir Texto Largo (o memo) de Access (VBA) a Word usando el siguiente código?

Tags: base-de-datos, vb.net, vba, ms-access, ms-word

Estoy trabajando en un programa con Access que trata de pasar, con un formulario, el registro determinado a una plantilla de word .dotx.

Encontre el código siguiente por internet, el cual he ido retocando (programado en vba):

```vb
'REFERENCIAS NECESARIAS:
'Menú -> Herramientas -> Referencias -> Microsoft Word Object Library

Public Function InformeWord( _
  ByVal plantilla_word As String, _
  ByVal Consulta As String, _
  Optional ByVal filtro As String = "" _
) As Boolean
On Error GoTo Errores

'Ejemplo de uso (evento al hacer clic de un botón de comando):
'=InformeWord("informe_cliente.dot";"tabla_clientes";"cliente_id=" & cliente_id)

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim campo As DAO.field
    Dim appWord As Word.Application
    Dim documento_word As Word.Document
    Dim ruta_actual As String

    If filtro <> "" Then
        Consulta = "SELECT * FROM " & Consulta & " WHERE " & filtro
    End If
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Consulta, dbOpenForwardOnly)

    If rs.BOF And rs.EOF Then
        'Nada
    Else

        Set appWord = New Word.Application
        appWord.Visible = False
        Call SysCmd(acSysCmdInitMeter, "Exportando a Word", 100)
        DoCmd.Hourglass True

        If plantilla_word = "" Then
            Set documento_word = appWord.Documents.Add()
        Else
            ruta_actual = Left(CurrentDb.Name, InStrRev(CurrentDb.Name, "\"))
            Set documento_word = appWord.Documents.Add(ruta_actual & plantilla_word)
        End If

        For Each campo In rs.Fields

            With appWord.Selection.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = "[" & UCase(campo.Name) & "]"
                With .Replacement
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .Text = rs(campo.Name) & ""
                End With
                Call .Execute(Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
            End With

        Next

    End If
    InformeWord = True
Salida:
On Error Resume Next
    appWord.Visible = True
    Call SysCmd(acSysCmdRemoveMeter)
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    Set appWord = Nothing
    Set documento_word = Nothing
    rs.Close: Set rs = Nothing
    Set campo = Nothing
    Exit Function
Errores:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "InformeWord"
    Resume Salida
End Function
```

Este código recoge el registro en el formulario y lo imprime en las casillas de la plantilla de Word marcadas con "[NOMBRE CAMPO EN ACCESS]" eliminado los carácteres "[" y "]".

El problema viene cuando intentas pasar texto mas grande de 255 carácteres, es decir, texto largo o también llamado memo. ¿Como deberia editar el código para que pueda transportar el Texto Largo a Word editando el código ya usado?

Aviso que soy bastante principiante con VBA pero he programado bastante con C con lo que me ayuda a entender ciertas cosas.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: *El problema viene cuando intentas pasar texto mas grande de 255 carácteres* ¿Por qué? ¿Qué línea falla? ¿Qué error te sale? Tu pregunta ahora es demasiado abierta, hay que concretar más.

Comment: No falla en ninguna linea. Al asociar el codigo a un boton en access y pasar un texto largo (+255) me salta un error en pantalla que el campo que estoy pasando es demasiado largo.